# Count the number of subdirectories without the execute bit

Tags: linux, bash

How can I count the number of subdirectories that **don't** have the execute bit set?

This is my attempt but is there a better or more elegant way?

```
count=0; for d in */; do [[ -d $d && ! -x $d ]] && (( ++count )); done
printf %s\\n "$count"
```

---

My main interest is in checking if the execute bit is not set for `all`.  That is not just for the current user.

Comment: Do you want to do it recursively? If you unset the x bit of a directory, you can't go into it so you would have to set it first. If your goal is not recursive, it should be doable.

Comment: @roccobaroccoSC I don't need it to be recursive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following counts directories without executable bit for current user:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d '!' -executable -printf . | wc -c
```

The following counts directories that have 0 executable bits:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d '!' -perm /111 -printf . | wc -c
```

The following counts directories that have 2 or less executable bits set:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d '!' -perm -111 -printf . | wc -c
```

Parts from `man find`:

> ```
>    -perm /mode                                                                                                                         
>           Any  of  the permission bits mode are set for the file.
>
>   -perm -mode
>           All  of the permission bits mode are set for the file.
>
>    -executable                                                                                                                         
>           Matches files which are executable and directories which are
>           searchable (in a file name resolution sense) by the  current
>           user.
> ```

Comment: Sure, because `.` is also a dir. Should be fixed.

Comment: I still think it is wrong. Maybe it is counting the total number of subdirs recursively that **do** have the execute bit?

Comment: Och,it's without. Here you go

Comment: Thanks. It's still counting recursively. Maybe add `-maxdepth 1`

Comment: `This line does not catch a directory with 600, 060 or 006 permissions` It writes "permission denied" for me, but still counts them. Och because it's trying to descend, then it works.

Comment: How about if I want to check if the execute bit is not set for all? I think your answer just checks if it is not set for the current user.

Comment: There is `-perm`, see `man find`, it has many options. You can do like `'!' '(' -perm o=x -o -perm g=x -o -perm o=x ')'`

Answer (score 0):

This oneliner should do. Add a `| wc -l` at the end if you want to just count the number:

```sh
ls | while read dir; do stat --printf="%A %n\n" "$dir"  | grep '^d' | grep -v '^d..x......' | grep -v '^d.....x...' | grep -v '^d........x'; done
```

And the result:

```sh
/tmp % mkdir b
/tmp % mkdir c
/tmp % chmod 600 a
/tmp % chmod 060 a
/tmp % chmod 600 a
/tmp % chmod 060 b
/tmp % chmod 006 c
/tmp % ls | while read dir; do stat --printf="%A %n\n" "$dir"  | grep '^d' | grep -v '^d..x......' | grep -v '^d.....x...' | grep -v '^d........x'; done
drw------- a
d---rw---- b
d------rw- c
```

Comment: Isn't parsing `ls` evil? As in http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: @Giraffe: why is it evil? the directory permissions are presented in a language neutral way.

Comment: All I know is in that link I pasted.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead

Comment: @KamilCuk: This line does not return the same results.